# web2py SQLFORM.factory defaults not updating

Tags: forms, web2py

I have an SQLFORM.factory on a page that I use to(among other things) update a particular field in a table. That field is a drop down table I made like so

```
Field('visibility',requires=IS_IN_SET(['everyone','subscribers','friends','nobody']))
```

So the field in the SQLFORM.factory looks the same. The difference is that I want the default in the SQLFORM.factory to be the current value of that field in a particular table. by making a default. I do a query on the desired entry on the table, select that field, and that becomes my default, the selected option. Perfect the first time you load it up.
I do the update after the form accepts like so and the update works functionally:

```
if subForm.accepts(request,session,dbio=True):
    if myForm.vars.visible != theDefault:
        db(row).update(visibility = subForm.vars.visibility)
```

If you submit the page the selected option is not the current value of that field in the table, it's always the one it was previous. If I look at my database admin the table updated fine but I could not fetch the right option to select as my default. If my default was 'everyone' and then I select and submit 'friends' then the selected when the page reload after the submit is still 'everyone' If I then select and submit  'nobody', after the refresh it is 'friends'.

If it helps, I am displaying the view this SQLFORM.factory is in in and iFrame as part of a bigger page.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, here's how you do it(sorta hackey but it works)

```
#This is a kludge to get the right default visibility selected
if request.vars.visible == None:
    visibleDefault = theDefault
else:
    visibleDefault = request.vars.visible

form = SQLFORM.factory(
       FIELD(Field('visible',requires=IS_IN_SET(['everyone','subscribers','friends','nobody'],zero=None),default=visibleDefault),
       table_name='table')

if form.accepts(request,session,dbio=True):
    if form.vars.visible != theDefault:
        db(row).update(visibility = form.vars.visible)
```